# Nested foreach() with different number of values

Tags: php

If i have two arrays

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11); // 11 values

$arr2 = array('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5'); // 5 values
```

it is clear they have different number of values

and i want to use `foreach()` to print out as follow

```
1-m1
2-m2
3-m3
4-m4
5-m5
6-m1 <--- it start pick from $arr2
7-m2
8-m3
9-m4
10-m5
11-m1 <--- it start pick from $arr2
```

each value from $arr1 will pick value of same key from `arr2` till `arr2` ends then will repick from the start of `$arr2` and so on

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple logic.

Define a variable (`$key`) outside of your loop (starting at 0 because array indexes start at 0), and create a variable (`$arr2_max`) to hold the max amount of values in `$arr2`.

On each loop, check if `$key` is equal to the max amount of values in `$arr2`, if it is, set `$key` back to 0. Also increment `$key` by 1 at the end of each loop.

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11); // 11 values

$arr2 = array('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5'); // 5 values

$key = 0;
$arr2_max = count($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $arr1_val) {
    if($key == $arr2_max) $key = 0;

    $arr2_val = $arr2[$key]; //this is the value from $arr2

    echo "$arr1_val-$arr2_val<br>";
    $key++;
}
```

Output:

```
1-m1
2-m2
3-m3
4-m4
5-m5
6-m1
7-m2
8-m3
9-m4
10-m5
11-m1
```

If your `$arr2` is not numerically indexed, first use `array_values()` to make it numerically indexed. `$arr2 = array_values($arr2);`

Answer (score 3):

You could just do a simple modulus operation to reset index back to zero on reaching size of $arr2.

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11); // 11 values

$arr2 = array('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5'); // 5 values

$size = count($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $index => $curr){
    echo $curr,"-",$arr2[$index % $size],PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/R6u2q

**Update:**

For arrays with non numerical keys, you could just do:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11); // 11 values

$arr2 = array('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5'); // 5 values

$values = array_values($arr2);

$size = count($arr2);

foreach($arr1 as $index => $curr){
    echo $curr,"-",$values[$index % $size],PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea. Though, for outside people reading the source code it may be pretty confusing (specifically people who haven't worked with modulus much), but that doesn't make it any less valid!

Comment: A simple comment in the code can defend doing it this way, then everyone would get it quicker. This is more "neat" than explicitly resetting a counter, but both are valid! Same thing goes here with `array_values()` as I mentioned on Grumpy's answer (likely not a problem in this question). :-)